# How to show the total number of sending and non-sending quizzes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am developing an intranet web application which is a Quiz Engine. Now, I need to come up with a query that shows the total number of sending & non-sending quizzes. The current query that I am using it right now is showing the number  of sending quizzes only:

```
SELECT COUNT(QuizID) AS [Total Number of Sending Quizzes] 
  FROM dbo.Quiz 
 WHERE (IsSent=1)
```

**So how should I modify it to get the total number of non-sending quizzes?**

For your information, the in the database, I have a table called Quiz Table that consists of: QuizID, Title, Description, IsSent.

IsSent is a flag/boolean that takes True (1) or False (0) to determine that the quiz is sent or not.

**EDIT:**

I want to get two columns: One called Total Number of Sent, and the second column as Total Number of not Sent. **How to get these columns?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be allow null is true of IsSent Column,So you should also handle this

```
SELECT 
        CASE WHEN Isnull(IsSent,0) = 0 THEN  'Total not Sent' 
        ELSE 'Total Sent'
        END 'Quiz Status'
        ,COUNT(QuizID) 'Count'
FROM    dbo.Quiz 
GROUP BY isnull(issent,0)
```

**Edit from comments:**

```
SELECT (  SELECT count(SeqID) 
          FROM   quiz 
          WHERE  issent = 1 ) AS 'Total Number of not Sent'  

      , ( SELECT count(SeqID) 
          FROM   quiz 
          WHERE  isnull(issent,0) = 0 ) AS 'Total Number of Sent'
```

Comment: However, how can I use it in my C# code since I need to refer to to the both counts: Total Sent and Total not Sent? Can I get them as two columns?

Comment: select 

 (select count(SeqID) from quiz where issent = 1)'Total Number of not Sent'
,(select count(SeqID) from quiz where isnull(issent,0) = 0)'Total Number of Sent'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(QuizID) AS [Total Number of Sending Quizzes] 
  FROM dbo.Quiz 
 GROUP BY IsSent
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group the result by value of `IsSent` column like following:

```
SELECT COUNT(QuizID),
        CASE WHEN IsSent = 1 THEN  [Total Number of Sending Quizzes] 
        ELSE [Total Number of Non-Sending Quizzes] 
        END [status]
FROM dbo.Quiz 
GROUP BY IsSent
```